# Cerrar etiqueta <img> de HTML

Tags: javascript

Estoy obteniendo una cadena de html de un editor de texto llamado **froala**, pero este editor no cierra las etiquetas `img`.

Como podria tomar una cadena html que contenga etiquetas de este tipo:

```
<img src="rutaxx" alt="altxx" class="classxxx">
```

y pasarlas a esto:

```
<img src="rutaxx" alt="altxx" class="classxxx"/>
```

Comment: Te recomiendo que te leas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para que veas como funciona el sitio y cómo preguntar. Deberías intentar primero solucionarlo por tu propio pie, y si no consigues solucionarlo o tienes algún error, preguntar poniendo tú código para que te podamos ayudar @NataliGamboa

Comment: En html5 no hace falta poner la barra en etiquetas de elementos vacíos (los que no requieren una etiqueta de cierre, como <br>, <img> o <hr> por ejemplo). ¿Hay algún motivo concreto por el que quieras añadírsela?

Comment: Si, porque la libreria que usa el backend para crear un pdf a partir de la cadena html, solo admite que las etiquetas <img> <br> o <hr> esten cerradas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esta función te podría servir:

Primero quitamos los espacios en blanco del inicio y del final con 
[**trim**](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_trim_string.asp).

Luego obtenemos todas las etiquetas de tipo `img` con el siguiente regex usando la función [**match**](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_match.asp):

```
/(<(img[^>]+)>)/ig
```

Esto te generará un array de strings con formato de tipo etiqueta `img`.

Luego insertamos el slash de cierre de etiqueta al final de tu cadena usando la función [**slice**](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_slice_array.asp) y volvemos a insertar la etiqueta modificada en la cadena.

```js
var cadena = ' <p><img src="i0.wp.com/wptavern.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/…\" class=\"fr-fic fr-dii\" style=\"width: 228px;"></p><p><span style="color: rgb(226, 80, 65);">esto es un parrafo en rojo</span></p> ';

// Quitamos los espacios en blanco
cadena = cadena.trim();

//Buscamos las etiquetas img dentro de la cadena
var tags = cadena.match(/(<(img[^>]+)>)/ig);
if (tags != null) {
  tags.forEach(function(tag, i) {

    // Guardamos la posición de la etiqueta
    var position = cadena.indexOf(tag);

    // Eliminamos la antigua etiqueta
    cadena = cadena.replace(tag, '');

    // Agregamos el "/" antes de cerrar la cadena
    tag = tag.slice(0, tag.length - 1) + "/" + tag.slice(tag.length - 1);

    // Insertamos la nueva etiqueta en la cadena
    cadena = [cadena.slice(0, position), tag, cadena.slice(position)].join('');

  });
}

console.log("Nueva Cadena: \n\n" + cadena);
```

Comment: El problema esta en que la cadena no solo contendria una etiqueta img, sino varias img y de cualquier tipo html , por ejemplo:                                                       <p><img src="https://i0.wp.com/wptavern.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/stack-overflow.png?ssl=1\" class=\"fr-fic fr-dii\" style=\"width: 228px;"></p><p><span style="color: rgb(226, 80, 65);">esto es un parrafo en rojo</span></p>

Comment: Ya arregle la funcion para que haga esas validaciones, dale una mirada

Comment: Infinitas gracias amigo :D.

Comment: hola,la funcion me elimina el texto que esta entre las etiquetas que no sean de img, mira: cadena inicial: <p>texto 1</p><p><span style="color: rgb(226, 80, 65);"><img src="blob:http://localhost:4200/a8604c45-6d26-4062-8e5b-421e005b1015" style="width: 149px;" class="fr-fic fr-dib fr-fil"></span></p>  cadena resultante: desaparece el texto 1 <p></p><p><span style="color: rgb(226, 80, 65);"><img src="blob:http://localhost:4200/a8604c45-6d26-4062-8e5b-421e005b1015" style="width: 149px;" class="fr-fic fr-dib fr-fil"/></span></p>

Comment: y cuando la cadena no tiene img, simplemente guarda una etiqueta <p></p> ignorando el resto de contenido

Comment: Ya arregle el metodo has pruebas a ver si funciona